# How can I change select options with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, select, jira

I have a select with options I need when I select an option another two disappear in the same select

```
<select class="select cf-select" name="customfield_10303" id="customfield_10303">
                <option value="">None</option>
                                <option value="10200">Opened</option>
                            <option value="10201">Closed</option>
                            <option value="10202">Escalated</option>
                            <option value="10203">Handled</option>
                            <option value="10204">Deferred</option>
                            <option value="10205">Reopened</option>
                            <option value="10206">Could Not Be Resolved</option>
        </select>
```

this is the HTML code I need javascript code when I select opened Just Escalated and Deferred are only appear

Comment: You forgot posting the code.

Comment: All you have posted is a goal, but not any code related problems associated with achieving that goal as outlined in [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: `I select Opened Just Escalated and Deferred are only appear` Ok. Why exactly these? According to what scheme?

Comment: I have my own scheme I need to know how the code will look like I need this to add in Jira custom field issues

Answer (score 1):

How exactly you need them to `disappear`? Here i just delete them from the DOM.

```js
const selector = document.querySelector("select");

selector.addEventListener("click", addActivityItem);

function addActivityItem(event) {
  let options = selector.querySelectorAll("option");
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].value !== event.target.value) options[i].remove()
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes I need something like this but I need to choose which appear and which disappear